# Precision required in an optimization problem causes a constraint not to be satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy, precision

I have successfully solved a massive optimization problem where I have found the values of some coefficients to distribute some quantities. One of the constraints is that the sum of these coefficients is equal to one, for each optimization problem.

For the delivery of results, I am asked that the values have less than six decimal places, so, once the optimization is finished, I round and I can have solutions like the following:

```
result1 = [0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111]

result2 = [0.159891, 0.119918, 0.000680, 0.599592, 0.119918, 0.000000]
```

Having done this rounding, I find that the sum of the results is not 1, but 0.999999.

A simple solution is to calculate all the coefficients but the last one, so that the last one is the one needed for the sum to be worth 1. For example:

```
result1 = [0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111111, 0.111112]

result2 = [0.159891, 0.119918, 0.000680, 0.599592, 0.119918, 0.000001]
```

Although in my case the above correction does not affect the result too much, it seems to me a very crude correction. For example, in result2 I am assigning part of the cast when originally it is not entitled to anything.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem, for example, by indicating in the same optimization process that I meet the constraint considering six decimal places?

Comment: There is no absolute answer to that, only choices to make. You could give the remainder to the largest number.

Comment: or the one with largest "rounding remainder".

Comment: I would suggest using the [iteround package](https://pypi.org/project/iteround/) to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to round high precision optimised coefficients to a fixed length with the optimum behaviour of the new coefficient set is still a research problem today with interesting new results occurring every now and then.

One reasonable heuristic that you could use is examine the sensitivity of your misfit to each of the free parameters and then tweak the one which makes the smallest possible change to the chi-squared (or whatever metric you are using for misfit). This may not be optimal since there could be a pair or a triple that could be altered in some systematic way to do better.

You could try taking the rounded coefficients that you have and make the simplifying assumption that the optimum solution is nearby and brute force search +/- 0.000003 either side of each one (that's ~7^N cases to search) looking for the best one. Real life optimisation problems although superficially smooth can have isolated spikes where the fit is unusually good. It is a known problem in rational approximations.

The other heuristic is to use your a priori knowledge of the constraint on the sum of the coefficients. So fit N-1 free parameters a_i and make the last one 1 - sum{a_i}. That doesn't quite work though if you have to report the answers to 6 places of decimals. You would need about 8 decimal places to specify a 32 bit real in decimal unambiguously and about 17 for a 64 bit double. You are are still at the mercy of the input output routines though...

For this reason when dealing in coefficients that have been the hard won as a result of long complex optimisation routines in best practice the results are usually shared with others in a [floating point hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882862/purpose-of-hexadecimal-floating-point-value) format which exactly represents the numerical value. That way you can be sure that the compiler or read floating point routine will generate the right constant.

Some decimal to float binary reading and writing routines ignore digits beyond 7 (float) or 16 (double) or on output gratuitously set them to zero even when they are not. Otherwise it can mean that the values you print out or save to a file in ASCII do not get the same fit when you read them back in again.